# Trouble running gazebo_ros2_control for iron/harmonic

Tags: gazebo-plugin, gazebo-ros-control, ros-iron

I am trying to run a basic example from gazebo_ros2_control - https://control.ros.org/master/doc/gz_ros2_control/doc/index.html

My Setup

1. Ubuntu 22.04
2. ROS Version - Iron
3. gz_ros2_control - main branch
4. ros2_control - iron branch
5. ros_gz - iron branch

I am trying the same example - example_position with no code changes.

```
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1706239497.991305480] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [ERROR] [1706239497.991395914] [controller_manager]: Loader for controller 'joint_state_broadcaster' (type 'joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster') not found.
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1706239497.991443230] [controller_manager]: Available classes:
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1706239497.991483967] [controller_manager]:   controller_manager/test_controller
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1706239497.991495926] [controller_manager]:   controller_manager/test_controller_failed_init
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1706239497.991502120] [controller_manager]:   controller_manager/test_controller_with_interfaces
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1706239497.991509840] [controller_manager]:   controller_manager/test_chainable_controller
```

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Apurv Saha, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, **what you saw & what you expected to see.** Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: You say you're trying to run a basic example, you show some console output, but there's no *question* here, no error messages, no description of a *problem.* It's not clear what you need help with or why you think something wrong has happened.

Answer (score -1):

We need to install the right controllers

Comment: What were the "right" controllers? Please [edit] and update your answer.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Apurv Saha. Thanks for your answer but we are looking for comprehensive answers that provide some explanation and context. Very short answers cannot do this, so please edit your answer to explain why it is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed. See [answer] for more info.

Comment: Similar issues here as with the original question: You need to install controllers for what? Which controllers did you need to install, how did you know those were the ones, how did you verify it solved your problem?

Comment: The important thing to remember is that StackExchange should be a *resource* for future visitors to *learn* from. If your friend had the same problem, would they be able to find your question by searching online (what in the question is unique to your situation)? Would they be able to use your answer here to solve that problem (does your answer contain enough detail to help)?